# How does WatchKit handle multiple map annotations on the same map?

Tags: ios, watchkit

In WatchKit, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceMap_class/index.html) for WKInterfaceMap specify that:

> "Tapping the map launches the Maps app on the user’s Apple Watch and
>   displays the corresponding location.

However: I want to show *multiple* map annotations on the map - is there a way to specify which map annotation will be displayed in Maps.app when the map is tapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in WatchOS 2 (at least), tapping on a WKInterfaceMap will open up the Watch's Maps app with the option the get directions to **the location that was at the centre point of your WKInterfaceMap**. When viewing these directions to this location it will be marked with a Red Pin annotation.

None of your custom annotations will be displayed in the Watch's Maps app.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no visibility as to exactly what happens when Apple Watch transitions from a WKInterfaceMap to Apple's native Maps application.

Try the [WatchKit Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/watchkit), exactly the right place for this question!

Answer (score 1):

You can use following methods to add multiple annotations. As per Apple documentation, currently only 5 annotations can be displayed on watch app's map

> addAnnotation:withPinColor
>
> addAnnotation:withImageNamed:centerOffset:
>
> addAnnotation:withPinColor:

Here is a sample code, which displays 2 annotations:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D mapLocation1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.787730, -122.403370);

CLLocationCoordinate2D mapLocation2 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.794873, -122.397892);

//
MKCoordinateSpan coordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1);

// Other colors include red and green pins
[self.map addAnnotation:mapLocation1 withPinColor: WKInterfaceMapPinColorPurple];

[self.map addAnnotation:mapLocation2 withPinColor: WKInterfaceMapPinColorRed];

[self.map setRegion:(MKCoordinateRegionMake(mapLocation, coordinateSpan))];
```

Comment: Thanks for the handsome answer, but this doesn't answer my question - I'm asking what behavior occurs when the map is tapped with multiple annotations.